# facelets 'target unreachable'

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, cdi

I am using maven, jsf 2.0, java ee 6, jpa and glassfish.  I have an initial web page which asks if you want to sign in or register.  If they say they want to sign in they are forwarded to a facelets/primefaces 3 which displays a login page with username and password text boxes.  For the username text field, its value is

> value="#{authenticator.username}"

and I get a

> "Target Unreachable, identifier 'authenticator' resolved to null"

I am using a beans.xml.  I have followed the naming conventions for CDI beans.
I inserted a log message in the Authenticator constructor, and it appears it never gets called because I do not get the message.

Another oddity is that once in a blue moon it works and I get something like the following:

> 07/08/2012 00:27:56.140 INFO  ...Authenticator - in Authenticator constructor
>
> 07/08/2012 00:27:56.171 INFO  ...Authenticator - getting Authenticator username
>
> 07/08/2012 00:27:56.171 INFO  ...Authenticator - in Authenticator constructor
>
> 07/08/2012 00:27:56.171 INFO  ...Authenticator - getting Authenticator password
>
> 07/08/2012 00:27:56.171 INFO  ...Authenticator - in Authenticator constructor
>
> 07/08/2012 00:27:56.171 INFO  ...Authenticator - getting Authenticator username
>
> 07/08/2012 00:27:56.171 INFO  ...Authenticator - in Authenticator constructor
>
> 07/08/2012 00:27:56.171 INFO  ...Authenticator - getting Authenticator password
>
> 07/08/2012 00:28:05.843 INFO  ...Authenticator - in Authenticator constructor
>
> 07/08/2012 00:28:05.843 INFO  ...Authenticator - in Authenticator constructor
>
> 07/08/2012 00:28:05.843 INFO  ...Authenticator - in Authenticator constructor
>
> 07/08/2012 00:28:05.843 INFO  ...Authenticator - getting Authenticator username
>
> 07/08/2012 00:28:05.843 INFO  ...Authenticator - in Authenticator constructor
>
> 07/08/2012 00:28:05.906 INFO  ...Authenticator - in Authenticator constructor
>
> 07/08/2012 00:28:05.906 INFO  ...Authenticator - getting Authenticator password
>
> 07/08/2012 00:28:26.000 INFO  ...Authenticator - in Authenticator constructor
>
> 07/08/2012 00:28:26.000 INFO  ...Authenticator - in Authenticator constructor`
>
> 07/08/2012 00:28:26.000 INFO  ...Authenticator - in Authenticator constructor
>
> 07/08/2012 00:28:26.031 INFO  ...Authenticator - in Authenticator constructor
>   07/08/2012 00:28:26.031 INFO  ...Authenticator - getting Authenticator password

When it does work, I do not understand why it calls the constructor so many times.

Here is managed (cdi) bean:

```
package com.mlb.mybills.view.user;

import com.mlb.mybills.i18n.Messages;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Named("authenticator")
@ViewScoped
public class Authenticator
{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Authenticator.class);

    private String username;
    private char[] password;

    public Authenticator()
    {
      log.info("in Authenticator constructor");
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
      log.info("getting Authenticator username");
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
      log.info("getting Authenticator username");
        this.username = username;
    }

    public char[] getPassword()
    {
      log.info("getting Authenticator password");
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(char[] password)
    {
        log.info("setting Authenticator password");
      this.password = password;
    }

public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        log.info("setting Authenticator password");
      this.password = password.toCharArray();
    }


   public String authenticate()
    {
      log.info("in Authenticator.authenticate");
        String result = null;
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
        try
        {
            request.login(username, new String(password));
            //result = "/private/group.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
         result = "/group.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }
        catch (ServletException ex)
        {
            log.error("Failed to authenticate user.", ex);
            Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
         FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, Messages.getString(
                    "Login.InvalidIdPasswordMessage", locale), null);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
        }
      log.info("result=" + result);
        return result;
    }

    public String logout()
    {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
        try
        {
            request.logout();
        }
        catch (ServletException servletEx)
        {
            log.warn("Failed to logout the user", servletEx);
        }
        return "/Login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

Comment: Post Authenticator managed bean code.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing bean management APIs. The `@Named` is from CDI, but the `@ViewScoped` is from JSF. You need to use the one or the other, not both on a single backing bean. Right now the bean is basically managed by CDI without any valid scope and hence the bean is constructed every time when the EL expression `#{authenticator}` is been resolved.

To fix the problem, if you intend to stick to CDI, use `@ConversationScoped` instead of `@ViewScoped`:

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
```

Or if you intend to stick to JSF, use `@ManagedBean` instead of `@Named`:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
```

The only disadvantage of the CDI approach is that you've to `@Inject` a `Conversation` as a property and then start and end it yourself.

Comment: +1 - but being able to start / stop a conversation (usually corresponding to the usecase) is definitely a feature, not a disadvantage...

Comment: @jan: I didn't mean to imply that it's a disadvantage per se, but only in the particular case when you intend to simulate the JSF view scope; using the JSF annotation is likely easier.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks, worked with JSF but not CDI when using @ConversationScoped or @RequestScoped and @Named. I have an empty beans.xml.  I noticed I use a `  String result = null;
  ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
  HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
  try
  {
   request.login(username, new String(password));
   //result = "/private/group.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
         result = "/group.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
  }`  That could be the culprit.  Is there a CDI way to get the request.

Comment: @BalusC if I use a FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext(), could that be the reason I am getting 'target unreachable' when using CDI

Comment: No, definitely not. Your problem of CDI not working is caused by something else which is above the managed bean layer.

Comment: @BalusC I am using maven and my empty beans.xml is in MyApp.war\WEB-INF\beans.xml.  My Named annotation is the camel case of my class name: `@Named("authenticator")`  Where else can I look?

Comment: Sorry, Maven is beyond me. Anything else looks okay.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bit of a problem because you're mixing CDI (@Named) and JSF (@ViewScoped) annotations. It's probably being called so many times due to this competition. You could look at Seam Faces, MyFaces CODI or roll your own version of ViewScoped for CDI, or drop CDI and go straight JSF.

Comment: That's because CODI and Seam 3 both hijack the JSF @ViewScoped annotation and convert it to a CDI scope.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for me although I do not understand it.  I found it in the following link: [a link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/myfaces-users/201111.mbox/%3CCAKcQ4qaW-+svfUdAQmUUeFtHXQ8=LoB9MnnC1V-UkneE7-wJ1w@mail.gmail.com%3E)!  Instead of just putting @RequestScoped and @Named I also added the following entry in faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
   <managed-bean-name>authenticator</managed-bean-name>
   <managed-bean-class>com.mlb.mybills.view.user.Authenticator</managed-bean-class>
   <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

With this I no longer got the target unreachable error.

Obviously I also corrected the above error noted by BalusC.  Thanks to all.